# apache redrict 301 from https://www.domain.com to https://domain.com

Tags: apache, http, ssl, https, url-rewriting

im trying for hours to redrict https:// www. domain .com to https:// domain .com with 301.

I have a certificate for domain .com but no wildcard for www. domain .com.

I tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond        %{HTTPS}        =on
RewriteCond        %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www\.meinedomain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule        ^(.*)            https://meinedomain.de/$1 [L,R=301]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

and

```
Redirect 301 / https://mineyourmind.de/
```

None of this works. Any ideas what could be wrong? I have added this directly to the apache settings and it is working great for http:// www. domain .com and http:// domain .com to https:// domain .com but not for https:// www. domain .com.

---

At the moment I use the following config. Every redrict works fine, instead of the https://www.mineyourmind.de to https://mineyourmind.de

How should such a file look like ?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mineyourmind.de
    ServerAlias www.mineyourmind.de
    Redirect 301 / https://mineyourmind.de/ 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin **
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mineyourmind
    ServerName mineyourmind.de
    ServerAlias www.mineyourmind.de
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/**
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/**
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/**
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/**

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mineyourmind/>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

---

Second Edit:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mineyourmind.de
    ServerAlias www.mineyourmind.de
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mineyourmind\.de$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://mineyourmind.de%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin **
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mineyourmind
    ServerName mineyourmind.de
    ServerAlias www.mineyourmind.de
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/**
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/**
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/**
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/**
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mineyourmind\.de$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://mineyourmind.de%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/mineyourmind/>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you request `https://www.meinedomain.de/` and your cert isn't authorized for `www.meinedomain.de`, then you'll get a security warning *regardless* of how you redirect. The redirect can only happen after they accept the security exception.

Make sure you've put those rules in the **SSL** vhost's config, not the non-SSL one. Apache usually has them separate. If that still doesn't work, you can try just putting this in an htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.meinedomain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://meinedomain.de%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: is still not working. tried it in the apache ssl site config and with a .htaccess.
Oc I get the warning because of the certificate but if I press go on, it still doesnt redrict.

Comment: I upgraded my SSL Certificate and www.mineyourmind.de is now supported.
But it is still not working. Do I have to create 4 virtual hosts? mineyourmind.de - www.mineyourmind.de - ssl_mineyourmind.de - ssl_www.mineoyurmind.de ?

Comment: @user2693017 No, you can use the `ServerAlias` directive and include whatever hostnames you want that vhost to handle. So you need a non-SSL vhost that handles `www.meinedomain.de` and `meinedomain.de`, then create an SSL vhost that also handles `www.meinedomain.de` and `meinedomain.de`.

Comment: @user2693017 your non-SSL vhost needs rules. And you need to add the rule from my answer to both the SSL and non-SSL vhosts

Comment: what do u mean with rules ?

Comment: @user2693017 mod-rewrite rules, the stuff starting from "RewriteEngine On" to the "RewriteRule".

Comment: mhh, the Redirect 301 / https://mineyourmind.de/ is working great for http and if I put ur whole code in and change the domain to the right one, the site wont load.

Comment: @user2693017 Why are you using a `Redirect`. Use the rules **that is in my answer** for *both* your vhosts.

Comment: updated the first post, do u see there anything thats wrong ?
should I replace <VirtualHost *:80/443> to <VirtualHost mineyourmind.de:80/443>